# Can I split my inventory quantity or trade with a team mate?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I've recently been playing in the squad game type. In about half of the matches I played, I scrounged up a ton of medical supplies where my team mates were unable to acquire anything.

Obviously the smart thing to do would be to split supplies with the team. When I can, I drop items on the ground for them to pick up.

**Is there a more effective way of splitting up loot with your squad? Or is there some way to split your inventory count so that you can drop it?**

For ex. I'd like to drop 3 of my 7 med kits so that my team may use them.

Comment: There is currently no way to split your items e.g holding ctrl and dragging or something else. I believe they are going to implement that, but atm there is nothing to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been implemented for a long time, CTRL Left+Right Click.

It looks like the people who binded "Crouch" on CTRL Left can't use it. Try binding it to another key. Not sure but you should try.

I use C to crouch and the split fonction works perfectly, but not for my friends who uses CTRL Left.

Comment: CTRL Left is the default for walking, but I'll give this a try and let oyu know what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right, my bad. But one thing is sure, I can split my items so you should be able to do it ! :)

Comment: You can also [CTRL Left]+Drag and Drop to the left side of your screen

Comment: Had a chance to give it a try yesterday and this is correct!

Comment: Nice, have fun ! This game is awesome !